# Resizing UIImage and saving

Tags: iphone, resize, uiimage, size

I am trying to figure out how I can shrink and save a UIImage, read it back in later, and then convert back to the original size without losing quality. I have managed to do the resizing and saving, but the problem is that if I save it smaller, when I read it back in and expand it, the quality is very poor. Does anyone know how this can be done without losing image quality?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to save the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't downsize the image and then bring it back without losing quality.  You can't make something out of nothing, once you lose the data you lose the data.

You will need to save two versions of the image, one large and one small.  This is a very typical scenario when dealing with thumbnails.

Check out the following site which provides categories for resizing images as well as several other really cool stuff:

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: The problem is that I have to send some form of data that can recreate the image, but it has to be under 4K. So I can't send a larger version as well. Here is the code I am using to shrink and save the image:  

UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:0.25 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]; 

outFileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage); 

str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i]; 

filePath = [gameFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:str]; 

[outFileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Comment: I tried doing the code indenting there but it didn't show up :/

Comment: If your requirements are to somehow send a high quality image that's under 4K over the web, I think you guys need to rethink your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot upsize a downsized image, you can display a downsized one while retaining a reference to the original image (which you can save):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
[image drawInRect: destinationRect];
UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
```

The destinationRect will be sized according to the dimensions of the downsized version.